# jQuery pointer to element which is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-parsing

I hope it's stupid, but my head is today right overloaded:) I have this code and I need to store the pointer on the element which is clicked on and pass it to the callback function. Exactly is it a submit button and after correct ajax submit of the form I want to delete content of them. I've tried lot of these parent(),children(),.. combinations, but it does not work:

```
$("form :submit").click(function () {  
            var element = this;  
            $(this).ajaxSubmit(function(payload, element){  
            $.nette.success(payload);  
            $(element).parent().children(".addStatusTextArea").val("");  
            hideMessage();  
        }  
    );  

    return false;  
});
```

Comment: What does your markup look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the element parameter from the function passed to ajaxSubmit.
i.e.

```
$("form :submit").click(function () {
    var element = this;
    $(this).ajaxSubmit(function(payload){
        $.nette.success(payload);
        $(element).parent().children(".addStatusTextArea").val("");
        hideMessage();
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `element` is *also* specified in your parameters for the callback, leave this out, like this:

```
$("form :submit").click(function() {
  var element = this;
  $(this).ajaxSubmit(function(payload) { //no element here in params
    $.nette.success(payload);
    $(element).parent().children(".addStatusTextArea").val("");
    hideMessage();
  });
  return false;
});
```

When it's in the parameters a *more* local `element` is defined, not what you set it to just before.  I'm not sure if your relative `.parent().children()` call is correct (it could be [`.siblings(".addStatusTextArea")`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) if it is) without seeing your markup...but your main issue is `element` not being what you want.